# Is there a provision to view data at any processing node of a flow in Mosaic?

Tags: debugging, amazon-s3, mosaic-decisions

We have a complex flow with more than 50 processing nodes to transform huge amount of data and dump the data into a single **Amazon S3** cluster. It is very difficult to understand if there is any issue in the data which is getting uploaded to **S3** when the flow completes.

**Is there any provision in Mosaic to look at the data which is getting processed at any of these 50 processing nodes?**

This will save a lot of our time and efforts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, In mosaic there is a node called **Peek** which can be used to view a sample output of any processed node to which it is connected. The output can be viewed in the **Data section** in flow canvas, once the flow is executed successfully.

**Following are the steps to use Peek node:**

1. From the list of Process nodes displayed, drag and drop Peek node on the canvas.
2. Double-click on Peek node to display the configuration window. The configuration window is divided into two sections, `INPUT` and `PROCESS`.
3. In the `PROCESS` section, enter the number of records to be displayed.

[image]

4. Click `OK`.

---

Now to view the resultant data, once your flow is executed successfully follow below steps -

1. Under `Run History`, click on your flow instance which will redirect you to the status view of your flow. You can recognize it by the green border that appears around the nodes.

[image]

[image: Flow Status View]

2. Now, double-click on the `Peek` node. This will enable the `Data` tab. Click on it to see your resultant data.

[image]